# ms-graph to outlook: getting error "invalid filter clause"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a simple enough API request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead eq false?$select=subject,body

But the returned JSON says "Invalid filter clause"

I've tried URL encoding (i.e. adding %20 for spaces): same result

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a typo here and that's the reason why this error occurs:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead eq false?$select=subject,body
                                                                                      ^
                                                               query options expects '&' instead of '?' as a delimiter
```

Here is a valid [OData URL](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead eq false&$select=subject,body
\_______________________________/\___________________________/ \__________________________________________/
                  |                               |                                  |
          service root URL                  resource path                  query options
```

Comment: Thanks very much Vadim. That was a dumb mistake!